# Return Values from front end form using ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am having trouble returning the values entered on my [front end form](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/using-acf_form-to-create-a-new-post/) to create a new post in Wordpress with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.  I have created a new field group and the form shows up fine on the front end, when I submit the form it submit with no title even though I have a title in the title box.  This is a text box I have in my field group with the name of 'title'.

According to the documentation I should be able to pass a $_POST variable but am having a tough time getting it to work or finding the $_POST variable.

Here is my page template which shows the form, creates a post but the post doesnt have a title.  So in a nutshell Im not sure how to retrieve the values to use in wp_insert_post:

```
<?php acf_form_head(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
function my_pre_save_post( $post_id )
{
    // check if this is to be a new post
    if( $post_id != 'new' )
    {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Create a new post
    $post = array(
        'post_status'  => 'publish' ,
        'post_title'  => $_POST['fields']['title'] ,
        'post_type'  => 'custom_gallery' ,
    );  

    // insert the post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post ); 

    // update $_POST['return']
    $_POST['return'] = add_query_arg( array('post_id' => $post_id), $_POST['return'] );    

    // return the new ID
    return $post_id;
}

add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'my_pre_save_post' );
?>
            <div id="content" class="clearfix row">

                <div id="main" class="col-sm-12 clearfix" role="main">

                    <?php 
                    acf_form(array(
                        'field_groups'        => array('31056'),
                        'post_id'       => 'new',
                        'submit_value'      => 'Submit Project'
                )); ?>

                </div> <!-- end #main -->

                <?php //get_sidebar(); // sidebar 1 ?>

            </div> <!-- end #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be including that function in the actual page template. It should be in **functions.php**

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/forms-actions
https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-frontend-display

Forms actions processes form you send and executes actions.